# Installing CCM client on PC via powershell

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm trying to speed up how soon SCCM recognises a device on the domain and starts the process of installing applications.

I have the below in powershell

```
$CCMInstallerPath = "\\ServerFQDN\SMS_MAN\Client\ccmsetup.exe"
$args = "/mp:MPServer", "/LOGON", "/UsePKICert", "SMSSLP=SMSSLPServer", "SMSSITECODE=MAN"
& $CCMInstallerPath $args
```

I get the below error:

```
Program 'ccmsetup.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:5
+     & $CCMInstallerPath $args
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:5
+     & $CCMInstallerPath $args
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I have read and execute access to this file, both by group and directly by name

I have also tried:

```
Start-Process -FilePath \\ServerFQDN\SMS_MAN\Client\ccmsetup.exe -ArgumentList "/mp:MPServer", "/logon SMSSITECODE-MAN", "/UsePKICert"
```

and get the error

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied.
At line:1 char:5
+     Start-Process -FilePath \\ServerFQDN\SMS_MAN\Client\c ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

---

ServerFQDN is a replacement for one of our NM servers
I can fully connect to the folder and run the exe manually
I am running elevated powershell

Comment: Are you running `Start-Process` locally on the new domain device, or remotely (like through a powershell session)? Is your admin user that you use to elevate powershell a domain user? Can you `Copy-Item` the .exe file to local, and if so, can you run it from there? Files on SMB shares have both NTFS File permissions, and SMB Share permissions applied, so you need at least Execute in both places.

Comment: All commands are running locally on the domain joined device. I have full admin rights on both a newly joined device and my own (testing on both). I've tried copy item and can pull the exe and the full folder path to the local machine, however when running from here get a separate error within software center after install has completed. I'm not currently with the new device so can't advise exactly what the error was at the moment

Comment: Can you see if the device actually has its ccm client cert? It should show up with `Get-Item Cert:\LocalMachine\my\*`. Your parameters may be ordered incorrectly - definitely move `SMSSITECODE-MAN` to the end (and I think the `-` is supposed to be an `=` here?). Based on this post, it looks like ccmsetup.exe might drop any `/x` flags coming after the first `a=b` option: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8fda3e26-b4ae-413f-9340-fc84a4228db5/

Comment: I've updated the question with the changes recommended, still getting the same error. The result from Get-Item Cert:\LocalMachine\my\* is Thumbprint: BE6EFAD89788D4458C46F08CF62112DC3C5165D2, Subject: *blank*

Comment: Does anything useful show up in `%WinDir%\ccmsetup\Logs\ccmsetup.log`?

Comment: Not on the fresh laptop, my current laptop with it already installed gives return code 0. Which isn't of much use... I've asked someone to look in to effective access for the file to see if there's anything going on here where I can't see

Comment: Can now confirm that the issue was caused by share permissions. While I had permissions the read and exec the exe there was an issue found in effective access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by incorrect share permissions found in effective access.

Permission was granted to run the file but effective access was showing differences